# How to get formatted date values in composite aggregation using terms?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using `composite` aggregation to combine multi aggregations at the same level.

For date fields; if i use `date_histogram` aggregations, i can get intervals in readable format unlike `terms` that returns values in milliseconds.

Meanwhile; inside `sources`, i can use `format` property for `date_histogram` only.

For instance:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "COLUMN": {
      "composite": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "date_histogram": {
              "date_histogram": {
                "field": "Ship Date",
                "interval": "year",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "terms": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "Ship Date"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It will return keys in milliseconds for `terms`, but required format for `date_histogram`.

```
{
    "key": {
        "date_histogram": "2015-01-01",
        "terms": 1420149600000
    },
    "doc_count": 4
}
```

The problem is i wanna get field values, no an intervals.

Is there any way to get date field values inside `composite` with format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is by using `script` property, like:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "function_score": {
      "composite": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "NAME": {
              "terms": {
                "script": {
                  "source": 
                  """
                  // Get each field value as string
                  String datetime = doc['Ship Date'].value.toString();

                  // Create format object based on string
                  DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM");

                  // cast datetime into ZonedDateTime to use format function
                  ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(datetime);

                  // return formatted date
                  return zdt.format(formatter);
                  """,
                  "lang": "painless"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, it will return values as required.

```
{
    "key": {
        "NAME": "April"
    },
    "doc_count": 319
}
```